# Using jquery to achieve animated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

I want a UI like http://demo.songpane.com/#/set/c/b for my webapp, can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this in jquery. Does it require jquery animation or something, Is there a plugin for that or do I have to write the code from the scratch. The page is divided into different moving divs.

Comment: take a look at bootstrap, it's a responsive framework much like what you're seeing on songpane.  btw, songpane is using angularjs for all their databinding and realtime updating.. very slick but you'll have to design the UI whereas bootstrap does the ui work for you.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example.  Check it out and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic example using only JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/7DSmK/

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
   $('#Content div').hide();
    var target = '#' + $(this).html();
    $(target).show('slow');
});
```

This simply hides all "content" divs and then shows the one you want, using a very simple animation built into JQuery.

To do anything more fancy, you'd want to use JQuery UI or CSS3 transitions.

http://jqueryui.com/animate/

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott & David for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to achieve animation.

You can use CSS `transition-duration` to specify an animation time. Then all you need to do is change the CSS rules in jQuery and they will animate.

The other is to use jQuery's [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method, which allows you to change CSS rules over a specified time period. jQuery has several shorthand methods built-in as well for animation, such as `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` for setting `display` of an element to `block` or `none`.

Neither can be accomplished without CSS, however, the animate method will probably give you the most flexibility, as it allows you to specify a different duration on each animation.

Of course there are libraries such as Bootstrap and jQueryUI that have built-in animation functions that you can simply call if you don't want to write the code yourself.